# Cuda enabled FFMPEG not showing any GPU usage

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cuda

I've compiled ffmpeg 4.3.1 with cuda support using the Toolkit 11. However, when I run ffmpeg against an rtsp stream and transcode into mp4, the process never shows any GPU usage in ProcessExplorer.If I run some of the samples provided with the Toolkit, I can see GPU usage; but not ffmpeg.

Any ideas why?

Windows 10
FFMPEG 4.3.1
NVidia toolkit 11
NVidia Quadro RTX3000

Output:

C:\ffmpeg>ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov -f rawvideo -c:v h264_nvenc test.mp4

ffmpeg version N-99601-g33624f4f2e Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27034 for x64
configuration: --toolchain=msvc --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --extra-cflags=-I/ffmpeg/nv_sdk --extra-ldflags='-libpath:/ffmpeg/nv_sdk'

libavutil      56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavcodec     58.111.101 / 58.111.101
libavformat    58. 62.100 / 58. 62.100
libavdevice    58. 11.102 / 58. 11.102
libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100

The rest of the putput

Output #0, rawvideo, to 'test.mp4':
Metadata:
title           : BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
encoder         : Lavf58.62.100
Stream #0:0: **Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main), cuda**, 240x160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Metadata:
**encoder         : Lavc58.111.101 h264_nvenc**

Thanks!